# Perl CPAN module fisher exact test

Tags: perl, statistics

Is there any module in CPAN that can provide a method to compute the Fishers exact tests?

example in R:

in a 2x2 contingency table like:

```
    17        12
    8842559   10003821

fisher.test(matrix(data = c(17,8842559,12,10003821), nrow = 2))


        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  counts
p-value = 0.2642
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.7213591 3.6778630
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  1.602697
```

I used [`Text::NSP::Measures::2D::Fisher`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aNSP%3a%3aMeasures%3a:2D%3a%3aFisher) module, but I am not sure it does the same as above.

```
use Text::NSP::Measures::2D::Fisher::twotailed;

my $npp = 10003821; 
my $n1p = 8842559; 
my $np1 = 12;  
my $n11 = 17;

my $twotailed_value = calculateStatistic(
    n11 => $n11,
    n1p => $n1p,
    np1 => $np1,
    npp => $npp,
);

if( (my $errorCode = getErrorCode()) ) {
  print STDERR $errorCode, " - ", getErrorMessage();
} else {
  print getStatisticName, "value for bigram is ", $twotailed_value, "\n";
}
```

but it does not give me anything

Comment: The module's one-line description: **Text::NSP::Measures::2D::Fisher - Perl module that provides methods to compute the Fishers exact tests.**  Perhaps you could include the code you used when using the module, and show how its results differ from what you expected.  If you're not sure the results match, you are in the best position to test and gain an assurance.

Comment: @DavidO Thanks, I aaded my code

Comment: That code does produce output for me: "*202 - Frequency value of ngram 'n11' must not exceed the marginal totals.*"  It should for you too.  And when I look up that error message in Text::NSP, it says, "*one of the frequency values(n11) exceeds the total no of bigrams(npp) or a marginal total(n1p, np1).*", which means nothing to me, but should probably mean something to one who has a need for this module.

Comment: ...but it probably is because `$n11` is set to 17 in your code, which is greater than `$np1`, which is set to 12.  Perhaps you're just putting the wrong value into the wrong position.  If I swap the 12 and the 17 in your code, I get "*Two Tailed Fishervalue for bigram is 0.0393735436982673*"

Comment: Yeah, given the diagram, `np1` and `n1p` both have to be `>= n11`, and `npp` has to be `>=` all three.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix differ from R to perl. You can't use the same matrix !

*for perl this is the matrix (into brackets):*

```
          word2   ~word2
  word1   [n11]     n12 | [n1p]
 ~word1    n21      n22 |  n2p
           --------------
          [np1]     np2   [npp]
```

*For R this is the matrix (into brackets):*

```
          word2   ~word2
  word1   [n11]    [n12] | n1p
 ~word1   [n21]    [n22] | n2p
           --------------
            np1     np2    npp
```